# I want to stop the condition after the event happen JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

(I mean when someone clicked the button se the change or create an Element one time, Please I know will work in another way but I need to know if I can solve it in this way....I appreciate your suppor)

```js
const BAG = document.querySelector('#container');
//const SMS = document.querySelector('#sms');
// const DEL = document.querySelector('#del');
BAG.addEventListener('click', function(apply) {
  var target = apply.target;

  if (target.id === 'sms') {
    console.log('Hi, Someone hit the Botton CLICK HERE');
  }
} else if (target.id === "del") {
  console.log('DELETE botton was clecked');
} else {
  console.log('^BODY was clecked');
}
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello!! Please click on the Botton Below</h1>
  <button id="sms">Click Here</button>
  <button id="del">Delete the Message</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is *very* unclear.  Please read **[ask]** and then update the question to give us clearer information.

Comment: thank you Archer for the great support, Ill do that!!

Comment: Are you looking for a onetime working button click or something like that ? Example if the user clicked on the button once then it should be non clickable like that ?

Comment: Dear Arunprasanth K V
100% correct but I need that in the way I wrote it and I don't know if that possible!
what do you think?
Many thanks for understand me

Comment: go for https://www.sitepoint.com/create-one-time-events-javascript/

Comment: Thank you so much, I‘ll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have added extra `{` that by code was not working ... updated code as below :

```js
var bag = document.querySelector('#container');
//const SMS = document.querySelector('#sms');
//const DEL = document.querySelector('#del');
bag.addEventListener('click', function(apply) {
  var target = apply.target;
  if (target.id === 'sms') {
console.log('Hi, Someone hit the Botton CLICK HERE');
target.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
  }

 else if (target.id === "del") {
  console.log('DELETE botton was clecked');
  target.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
} else {
  console.log('^BODY was clecked');
}
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Hello!! Please click on the Botton Below</h1>
  <button id="sms">Click Here</button>
  <button id="del">Delete the Message</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, maybe when I make the formatting for the code was I had a mistake. However my question is: I want the Event work JUST one time on the Button (Click Here) .
Thank you SantoshK so much in Advance if you helpe me or not :)

Comment: @MustafaAlAwad code updated which will show after first click button will be disabled

Comment: Many Many Thanks, you give to me the inspiration to solve it.

Comment: pls mark as a solution of above question

Comment: #SantoshK sorrry for the daly but how to make that?